# Wrong quota limit for Azure Synapse Workspaces

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

When I tried to create Azure Synapse Workspace I get below error:

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ReachedPerSubscriptionWorkspaceLimit","message":"Reached the maximum number of Synapse workspaces allowed for this subscription. Please contact Microsoft support to request an exception. Subscription: xxxx. Subscription offer type: PayAsYouGo. Current maximum: 0."}]}

I see that the limit is 20 workspaces, but as in error I don't have any created now. I even created a ticket to increate the quota from 20 to 30, but still have the same error.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now from Microsoft.